# Haskell Monad Functions

Tags: haskell, puzzle, monads, ghc

I'm going through a Haskell tutorial and am given this piece of code to do with moving a knight in chess:

```
import Control.Monad

type KnightPos = (Int,Int)

moveKnight :: KnightPos -> [KnightPos]  
moveKnight (c,r) = do  
    (c',r') <- [(c+2,r-1),(c+2,r+1),(c-2,r-1),(c-2,r+1)  
               ,(c+1,r-2),(c+1,r+2),(c-1,r-2),(c-1,r+2)  
               ]  
    guard (c' `elem` [1..8] && r' `elem` [1..8])
    return (c',r')

in3 :: KnightPos -> [KnightPos]
in3 start = return start >>= moveKnight >>= moveKnight >>= moveKnight

canReachIn3 :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> Bool
canReachIn3 start end = end `elem` in3 start
```

An exercise is to modify the functions so that `canReachIn3` tells you what moves you can take to get to the end position if it is possible to get there.

This tutorial has basically no exercises so I'm having trouble with basic stuff like this...I was thinking of changing the return values of all 3 functions to [[KnightPos]] where 1 big list contains a list for every possible ordering of moves. That would probably then involve moveKnight having a `[KnightPos]` parameter instead of a `KnightPos` one, which would then defeat the whole point of monads right?

Any help/thoughts would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might help to step back from the Monad concept for a bit when thinking about this code, if you find that plain old list operations are more natural for you.  So you can rewrite the example code (with a little bit of cleanup for legibility) as:

```
type KnightPos = (Int,Int)

moveKnight :: KnightPos -> [KnightPos]  
moveKnight (c,r) = filter legal candidates where
    candidates = [(c+2,r-1), (c+2,r+1), (c-2,r-1), (c-2,r+1),
                  (c+1,r-2), (c+1,r+2), (c-1,r-2), (c-1,r+2)]
    legal (c',r') = c' `elem` [1..8] && r' `elem` [1..8]

in3 :: KnightPos -> [KnightPos]
in3 start = concatMap moveKnight (concatMap moveKnight (moveKnight start))

canReachIn3 :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> Bool
canReachIn3 start end = end `elem` in3 start
```

The secret sauce is in `concatMap`.  As you probably know already, it's synonymous with `>>=` in the `List` monad, but it might be more helpful right now to think of it as mapping a function of type `KnightPos -> [KnightPos]` over a list `[KnightPos]` to yield a list of lists `[[KnightPos]]`, and then flattening the result back into a single list.

Okay, so now that we've dispensed with monads for the moment, let's look back at the puzzle...  Let's say your initial `KnightPos` is `(4,4)`, and you want to track all possible sequences of moves from that position.  So define another type synonym:

```
type Sequence = [KnightPos]
```

Then you'd want `moveKnight` to operate on these sequences, finding all possible moves from the last position in the sequence:

```
moveKnight :: Sequence -> [Sequence]
```

So starting from a sequence `[(4,4)]`, we'd get the list of sequences: `[[(4,4), (6,3)], [(4,4), (6,5)], [(4,4), (2,3)], ... ]`.  Then I think the only change you'd need to make to `in3` is to fix its type signature accordingly:

```
in3 :: Sequence -> [Sequence]
```

I don't think the actual implementation changes.  Finally, you'll want `canReachIn3` to look something like:

```
canReachIn3 :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> [Sequence]
```

I'm leaving the implementation detail out here on purpose since I don't want to ruin the puzzle for you entirely, but I'm hoping I've illustrated the point here that there isn't anything particularly "special" about a list, or a list of lists, or whatever.  All we've really done is substituted a function of type `KnightPos -> [KnightPos]` with a new function of type `Sequence -> [Sequence]` -- pretty much the same shape.  So fill in the implementations of each function using whatever style feels natural, and then once you have it working, go back to the monadic style, replacing `concatMap` with `>>=` and so on.

Comment: Thanks you gave me enough to let me persist for myself.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest making `KnightPos` a data structure capable of holding not only the current potion, but also the `KnightPos` that it came from:

```
data KnightPos = KnightPos {history :: Maybe KnightPos, position :: (Int,Int) }
```

You then need to implement the Eq and Show classes, and fix `moveKnight` so that it returns this structure with its history set appropriately:

```
moveKnight :: KnightPos -> [KnightPos]  
moveKnight p@KnightPos{position = (c,r)} = do  
    (c',r') <- [(c+2,r-1),(c+2,r+1),(c-2,r-1),(c-2,r+1)  
               ,(c+1,r-2),(c+1,r+2),(c-1,r-2),(c-1,r+2)  
               ]  
    guard (c' `elem` [1..8] && r' `elem` [1..8])
    return $ KnightPos (Just p) (c',r')
```

Make sure you understand the last line of this function.

The function `in3` should now work without modification.  I wrote a new function,`pathIn3 :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> [[KinghtPos]]` that returns all possible paths from `start` to `end` in 3 monadic statements.

**Spoiler Alert**

> pathIn3 :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> [[KnightPos]]
>     pathIn3 start end = do
>       p <- in3 start
>       guard (p == end)
>       return $ getHistory p

Answer (score 2):

"That would probably then involve moveKnight having a `[KnightPos]` parameter instead of a `KnightPos` one..."
No, you wouldn't want to do that. Keep the functions as basic as possible.

"...which would then defeat the whole point of monads right?"
Well, if you want all *orderings* of moves, you just don't in every move use the `join` implied in `>>=`. You might define a function returning a list of all paths of length *n* from a given starting point, where we may implement those paths as list of the positions passed, for efficiency reasons in reverse order.

```
waysFrom :: KnightPos -> Int -> [[KnightPos]]
```

First for one move (or zero)

```
waysFrom start 0 = [[start]]
waysFrom start 1 = map (\t -> [t, start]) $ moveKnight start
```

and then for arbitrary numbers of moves, at which point you can use again use `>>=` to join the trie-like structure resulting from straightforward recursion to a list of move lists:

```
waysFrom start n = waysFrom start (n-1) >>= (\w -> [t:w | t<-moveKnight$head w])
```

there may be a better way to do this, but it wouldn't actually "defeat" the whole point of monads.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading the tutorial and my solution is a little bit change functions `in3` and `canReachIn3`

```
in3 :: KnightPos -> [[KnightPos]]
in3 start = do
    first <- moveKnight start
    second <- moveKnight first
    third <- moveKnight second
    return [start, first, second, third]

canReachIn3 :: KnightPos -> KnightPos -> [[KnightPos]]
canReachIn3 start end = filter (elem end) $ in3 start
```

The result of `in3` contains list all possible paths.